# objective c afterDelay

Tags: objective-c

I'm using this call to switch image every 4 seconds:

```
 - (void) settheimage {
   cur+=1;
   waits=0;
   [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(settheimage)   object:nil];
   jpg = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@_%d",current_anim,current_anim, cur];
   img = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:jpg ofType:@"jpg"]];
    [self performSelector:@selector(settheimage) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.0];
}
```

it works on the first image but after that it crashes.
i don't want to use uiimage animation because i have a lot of images and the loading of the uiimage animation takes a lot of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that `current_anim` is (auto)released by the time your method is called, leading to a dangling pointer and crash (`EXC_BADACCESS`, I suppose?). You need to retain it manually, make it a retained property, or start using ARC.

In either case, you should [read something](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH) about memory management.